# Instalar o Codeigniter 2.1

Tags: php

Sabem como instalar o Codeigniter 2.1 corretamente porquê estou usando um script com ele mas não funciona e vi também que precisa de .htaccess sabem qual é o .htaccess dele?

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque não fornece as informações necessárias para diagnosticar o problema. Coloque mais detalhes do seu sistema e poderemos ajudá-lo. E redija a pergunta tornando-a mais clara.

Answer (score 4):

Primeira coisa: existe um site oficial do CodeIgniter (https://ellislab.com) e existe também um lugar aonde pode encontrar toda a documentação em inglês (https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/index.html) aonde ali na direita em preto existe uma aba para clicar que está escrito **TABLE OF CONTENTS**.

Vou te passar um link bem especial, o do manual de instalação ... em inglês (https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/installation/index.html).

Bom os passos são simples:

Você

- Faz download do Framework (https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/download);
- Descompacta todo o conteúdo dentro do seu servidor local ou hospedagem;
- Vai no PHPMyAdmin e cria um banco com usuário e senha para seu CI;
- E configura tudo dentro desse arquivo: `application/config/config.php`
- E desse também: `application/config/database.php`